# How to change ISO date format to string format("DD/MM/YYYY") in Couchbase query?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a date attribute in document in the below format

```
 2016-09-23T18:48:11.000+00:00
```

I need to convert this format into below format

```
“DD/MM/YYYY”
```

Is there any method to convert so?

I tried the below query :-

```
SELECT  date_format_str("2016-09-23T18:48:11.000+00:00", '11-11-1111' ) ;
```

Result :-

```
[
    {
        "$1": "2016-09-23T18:48:11Z"
    }
]
```

Expected Result :-

```
"23/09/2016"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be accomplished with `DATE_FORMAT_STR`

For your example;

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT_STR("2016-09-23T18:48:11.000+0000", "DD/MM/YYYY") AS formatted_date
```

For more information; https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html#fn-date-format-str

Comment: I am getting the result as 
[
  {
    "formatted_date": "2016-09-23T18:48:11Z"
  }
]

Comment: But I am expecting "23/09/2016"

Comment: Can you try `SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-09-23T18:48:11.000+00:00'), 'dd/MM/yyyy')`?

Comment: its stating as 
"msg": "Invalid function CONVERT (near line 1, column 21) (resolving to default:CONVERT)",

Comment: when used "1111/11/11" it doesn't know which part is DD which is MM , so use "DD/MM/YYYY"

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the Server version

Check various tabs

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html#date-string

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT_STR("2016-09-23T18:48:11.000+0000", "%d/%m/%Y") AS formatted_date;

SELECT DATE_FORMAT_STR("2016-09-23T18:48:11.000+0000", "DD/MM/YYYY") AS formatted_date;
```

If you get error that your version may not supported. You can use as follows

```
SELECT CONCAT2("/",SUBSTR(date,8,2), SUBSTR(date,5,2), SUBSTR(date,0,4)) AS newdate LET  date = "2016-09-23T18:48:11.000+0000";
```

Comment: thank you for the help, the first and the second one both of them are working in my Couchbase version

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT_STR("2016-09-23T18:48:11.000+0000", "DD/MM/YYYY") AS formatted_date;  when used "1111/11/11" it doesn't know which part is DD which is MM